# Vector of objects search for future objects' use?

Tags: c++, vector

I have data file which is being read into a vector. Example :

```
West Ham 38 12
Leicester City 38 13
```

In actual file there is more doubles followed the name. Anyways, previously I've used this kind of search:

```
vector<Team>newTeams; //vector of Team objects

string homeName;
cout << "Enter home team name: ";
cin >> homeName;
cout << endl;

Team ht;

for(Team team : newTeams)
{
    if(team.getName() == homeTeam)
    {
       ht = team;
    }
}
```

Basically I go through a vector and look for a specific team name. If I found team name, I assigned team to ht. Then, I would use ht to get needed data, i.e.:

```
ht.getHomeGamesPlayed();
ht.getPoints();
ht.getHomeGoalsScored();
```

So, my question is: is there a better way for search?(Use map of names + vector of doubles?):

```
map<name, vector<doubles>>;
```

Also, how do I make search case insensitive? i.e I type in leicester instead of Leicester CIty, and Leicester City would still get picked?

**UPD:** 
Seems like I figured it out, here's the code if you're interested:

```
string homeName;
cout << "Name: " << endl;
cin >> homeName;

Team ht;

for (Team team : dataTable) {
    if (strstr(team.getName().c_str(), homeName.c_str()))
    {
        ht = team;
    }
}
```

So when I type Leic it picks Leicester City(when I type leic, it doesn't work though)

Comment: Unrelated, but I hope you intended on the multiple places in this code where copy-assignment is happening. Apparently your class hasn't covered *references* yet.

Comment: Copy assignment is generally ok when you're copying small objects.... but yes Team const & might be better...

Comment: @WhozCraig if you can show me how to use reference in my example, I'll be more than happy to learn(I'm not taking any classes now, this is just for fun)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::map` would be a better fit for your problem. So would `std::unordered_map`.

To get case insensitive matches, you can use a string that has been converted to all upper case or all lower case as the map key. Then store the original name separately.

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::vector<double>>> mymap;
```

If you need partial matches, e.g. finding `Leicester City` when you type `leicester`, the vector approach you're using now might be best. If you need to match only on the *first* part of the name, you can still use `std::map` and use `map::lower_bound` to find a starting place for your search.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to this problem. The one I'd suggest is a radix tree with multiple input positions.

First, create a map or set or whatever to hold your objects. Then, you create a radix tree, indexing each partial match of some given width, e.g.

abcde fge

creates an entry for "abcde fge", "bcde fge", "cde fge", ... "e". pointing to your (multi)map value. You can use the property of radix trees that you can easily find all values with a given prefix to perform a fast search to find all matches for a given substring in around O(1) (or O(N) in an N size search term) provided you have a fixed input size. Note however that construction of the tree scales in O(n^2) of the size of the searchable material, in order to remedy this, you can limit the size of the search terms (e.g. 50 characters) that are indexed, or index in increments  followed by multiple searches (e.g. index "abcdefg" "cdefg" and "efg", then when searching for "def" you search for "def" and "ef", "ef" results in a prefix match with efg.)

Note that the search string must be at least as long as the width you skip, otherwise you'd have to search entire trees..